# Staticfile deployment fails with [ERR] bash: node: command not found

Tags: node.js, nginx, cloud-foundry

Spec:

- Angular CLI: 8.3.29
- Node: 12.22.1
- OS: linux x64
- Angular: 8.2.14

Manifest file:

```yaml
---
applications:
- name: test-app-ui
  memory: 2G
  path: dist
  buildpacks:
    - staticfile_buildpack 
  instances: 1
```

I created the `dist` directory by running `ng build`. Then pushed to CF and in the app logs, I got this error:

```
[ERR] bash: node: command not found
```

I thought CF should use NGINX to serve these static files in `dist` directory rather than running looking for `node` server?

In the app settings page, I see this:

> Buildpack: staticfile v1.5.15
>
> Start Command: node main.js
>
> Stack: cflinuxfs3 (Cloud Foundry Linux-based filesystem - Ubuntu
> Bionic 18.04 LTS)

So looks like `node` is required to get the app started but why isn't `node` available out-of-the-box in this buildpack?

Comment: That's very close to what I have for e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats, which works fine - the Staticfile buildpack indeed uses NGINX and shouldn't need to build anything. What does `cf buildpacks` tell you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I JUST went to the Setting and noticed that the start command is like this: `Start Command: node main.js` 

So I guess that's how this buildpack starts the app. Why doesn't this buildpack have `node` inside it, I have no idea...

Comment: Where I have the above app deployed I see `staticfile v1.5.15` but `Start Command: $HOME/boot.sh`, which is the correct start command for that buildpack. I'm not sure where you're deploying to but it looks like it's not correctly configured. Have you ever set a non-default start command for that app via the [manifest file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#start-commands) or [CLI](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/v6/push.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually didn't set any commands.

Comment: It's been set by somebody, that's not the buildpack default: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/blob/master/bin/release#L4. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/start-restart-restage.html#revert for how to get back to that. Unless your organisation is running a custom buildpack with the wrong start command, in which case you'll need to talk to your administrators.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thx! after setting the command you mentioned, it's working now! You're a genius! Let me know where you at and I'll buy a coffee one day. No kidding, man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Start Command: node main.js
```

is not correct for the Staticfile buildpack, which doesn't contain Node at all; the default and correct value (see e.g. [the repo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack/blob/master/bin/release#L4)) is:

```
Start Command: $HOME/boot.sh
```

It's probable that at some point someone has overridden that, either via [`cf push -c ...`](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/v6/push.html) or with a [`command:`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#start-commands) in the manifest file. You can reset back to the buildpack default using either of the methods shown [in the docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/start-restart-restage.html#revert):

- `cf push -c null ...`; or
- `command: null` in the manifest.

If that doesn't work, and the actual buildpack default is incorrect, you need to talk to your administrators to get that fixed (likely you're using a custom buildpack within your organisation) and in the meantime you could explicitly set `$HOME/boot.sh` using either method above.